# Using RegEx to find if text includes something you don't want?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I have this code:

```
import re

txt = "If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW') and MARM.MEINH = 'CS', then AUSP.MATNR exists in MARC.MATNR"

x = re.search("MARA.", txt)

if x:
  print(Match")
else:
  print("No match")
```

I want it to be "No Match" if there is any another prefix before the "." besides MARA. So this one should say no match because there is "MARM."

but this one

```
txt = "If MARA.MTART in ('ZPLW', 'ZFTW'), then MARA.MATNR = 1111"
```

would say Match

Comment: This isn't a CSV. It would be better to just remove that from the question. So, what is it? It seems to be some sort of programming language. You may want to approach it that way - maybe use some sort of lex/yacc parser toolchain.

Comment: Well it is just text hosted inside of row 1 of an excel sheet. it goes line by line. I turned the excel sheet into a csv.

Comment: That's not an Excel sheet.  That's a text file.  You may be looking at it in Excel because it claims the .csv extension, but you should be using a plain text editor.  I'm dubious of your output format.  It looks like you are creating an SQL `WHERE` clause.  How will you handle the "and" matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` to create a list of these prefixes using this regular expression (based off of the text you provided: `\w{4}\.`

So you could use it like this to make a list:

```py
prefixes = re.findall(r"\w{4}\.",txt)
```

which is equal to `['MARA.', 'MARM.', 'AUSP.', 'MARC.']`

Use this to check that they're all equal to "MARA." like this:

```py
all(element == "MARA." for element in re.findall(r"\w{4}\.",txt))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe are you looking for something like this?

```
x = all(['MARA.' in x for x in re.findall('[A-Z0-9]+\.[A-Z0-9]+', txt)])
```